# Undefined reference linker error to my first C++ project

Tags: c++

My project is [here](https://github.com/ibalampanis/distributed-training-of-recurrent-neural-networks-by-fgm-protocol).

I'm trying to run GMNetEEG executable and I see 3 undefined reference linker errors.

Here is the error.

Linker Errors:

[image]

Could you help me?
It's my first time that I posting here, so please be comprehensive with posting mistakes! Thank you!

Comment: Please show us how you build your project.

Comment: This project is integrated into CLion. So CMakeLists.txt helps the compilation process. I think that the problem is at cpp/exp/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, but post text as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation for the template is done in the cc file => "cpp/networks/controller.cc"

Normally when you build the library, it does not know what instances you will need,
so to fix your issue, you could include "#include "cpp/networks/controller.cc" instead of "#include "cpp/networks/controller.hh" in "cpp/exp/gm_net_eeg.cc"

Comment: I made this, and I have a lot of other undefined references. Could you explain further my problem? May I need to change all .hh includes to .cc?

Comment: depends what kind of errors you have now. The basic idea is that unless in the dml library there is a: "controller::Controller<gm_network::GmNet>" instance, it will be undefined, because your library has created only the types you needed at the time.

Comment: It worked like a charm! I changed incudes from .hh to .cc on all dependencies. Thank you, Nicolae!

Comment: Great to hear! :)